# Heroku and Salesforce Integration workbook error

Tags: integration, heroku

I am doing Integration between Salesforce and Heroku using the Integration Workbook and I came across this while  doing the tutorial #3 step 2.
When I refresh my app in the browser on the following URL
https://sheltered-savannah-2269.herokuapp.com/
I am landed on this page.
The page looks like this after the error.Do any one let me know how to correct this.
type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet spring threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 30 in XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 30; columnNumber: 16; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'fss:oauth'.
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:522)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:436)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 30; columnNumber: 16; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'fss:oauth'.
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:325)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:458)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3237)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1917)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:746)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:379)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2786)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:347)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:522)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:436)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.22 logs.

Apache Tomca

Comment: I received the same error when was practising the workbook few days back. Most likely it's due to the heroku app and not because of any git migrations we did. You may like to contact [joshua.birk] at salesforce.com or [jhurst] at salesforce.com. These guys are repo owners

Comment: I didn't find a way to reach Joshua.birk, but I raised a ticket with GITHUB and waiting for their response.

Comment: I did provide you their emails in my previous comment. I can't explicitly write them due to various security reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Doug B's answer helped me. But few things i had to figure out. So for the sake of completeness adding one more answer here:

So, Basically there is issue with media.

Here are steps to solve this problem:
1) Edit file named spring-mvc-fulfillment-base\src\main\resources\applicationContext.xml
2) Find line http://media.developerforce.com/schema/force-springsecurity-1.3.xsd
3) Replace it with http://force-spring.herokuapp.com/force-springsecurity-1.2.xsd
4) go to command prompt and run 'git diff'. It should show your changes.
5) Run 'git commit -m "Changing xsd"'
6) Above command will commit your changes.
7) Run 'git push heroku master' to submit your code to heroku

Note that force-springsecurity-1.2.xsd hosted by iandrosov. So for production/reliability/availability you should host it on your server.

Comment: This got me in the right direction, however, step 5 failed with the message: Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 11 commits. (use "git push" to publish your local commits) "git push" doesn't do it for me, it requests me to log in on Github. I know almost nothing about git, so I am going to google how to get past this obstacle.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue going through the workbook. I detailed how I resolved this in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711186/the-matching-wildcard-is-strict-but-no-declaration-can-be-found-for-element-fs/30905305#30905305).